# Kubuntu 14.04.4 LTS: mouse pointer disapeared

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, mouse, cursor

I am running Kubuntu 14.04 LTS since years without this problem. But last week my mouse cursor did disappear while working with the system (when closing some windows and switching between virtual desktops). I did not find a way to bring the mouse cursor back without restarting X. Switching to console and back to X did not change anything. The mouse cursor still did work, but it was invisible.

Today this happened again!? As I did not change the hardware, it seems that this issue was introduced with some of the last updates?

Does anybody have an idea how to bring the cursor back if it happens again?

Answer (score 0):

I had almost exactly the same problem when moved to kernel 4.5.1.

After adding kernel parameters, it appeared again.

You could try to add these two parameters:

```
i8042.nomux=1 i8042.reset
```

to `/etc/default/grub file` to variable `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`

Remove hash sign before that line to make effect.

Finally, save file, and update grub with `grub-update` command. Run with `sudo` or as root user. Then reboot the machine.